# Argentina or Argentine?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, parts-of-speech

In the following extract, should "Argentina" or "Argentine" be used?

> The images, which show Messi and other **Argentina** / **Argentine** players celebrating their 2022 World Cup win, have racked up over 67 million likes on the social media platform within hours of being posted.

https://edition.cnn.com/2022/12/21/business/messi-most-liked-instagram-post-intl-hnk/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular usage, Argentina is the name [as well as localisation] of the team, Argentine is descriptive of the player's nationality. This makes both versions correct, depending on your intent.

> Messi and other Argentina players

Messi and other players in the Argentina team

> Messi and other Argentine players

Messi and other players of Argentine nationality.

Equally…

> Smith and the other England players

or

> Smith and the other English players

by the same rules.

It just so happens that for a national football team, both should always be true - you need to be of that nationality to play for that team.

This wouldn't work for a League team, say Manchester - as there is no necessity at all that any Manchester player is actually Mancunian. Worse still for Arsenal - as there's no such 'localisation' as Arsenallian… there's not even a word to describe someone from Arsenal. It doesn't really even exist as a place near the team's ground, as they moved across the river from Woolwich Arsenal [an old munitions factory] over a century ago.

Answer (score 2):

"Argentina" is a noun. "Argentine" is an adjective. So normally we would say "Argentine players celebrating ...".

Nouns can be used as adjectives. Like we say "car keys" to mean keys for a car, using the noun "car" as an adjective. So you could say, "Argentina players celebrating ..." But most English speakers wouldn't. Usually we only use a noun as an adjective when there isn't a specific adjective form of the word.

Comment: Until recently, Argentina was called 'The Argentine' in UK and US English.

Comment: No, the noun "car" is **not** used as an adjective in "car keys": it has none of the attributes of adjectives other than being used to modify a noun. It is a noun modifying another noun.

Comment: @ColinFine Hmm. According to the American Heritage Dictionary, an "adjective" is "the part of speech that modifies a noun". https://grammarbrain.com/nouns-used-as-adjectives/ describes this idea as "nouns used as adjectives". They don't use the example of "car keys", but they do use "race car" and "history teacher". Perhaps there is some technical distinction one could make between "adjectives" and whatever you want to call nouns that are used to modify other nouns, but I was taught this as "nouns acting as adjectives" and I can find numerous sources on the web that describe it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If "Argentine" is used in the sense of an adjective/demonym to describe people / a person from Argentina (synonym of "Argentinian"), then I think the correct word would be "Argentine". It would be an adjective modifying the noun "players".